# Adjusting the Invoke call to cater for methods that return void and non-void types

Tags: c#

How would I adjust the following `Invoke` call so that it caters for methods that return void and non-void types?

At the moment `ErrorHandlingComponent.Invoke` expects a `Func<T>` as its first parameter. I've found that when I'm trying to pass it a void method, the compiler complains.

```
    public static T Invoke<T>(Func<T> func, int tryCount, TimeSpan tryInterval)
    {
        if (tryCount < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("tryCount");
        }

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return func();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (--tryCount > 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(tryInterval);
                    continue;
                }
                LogError(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. A `Func` delegate is designed so that it always returns something.

The easiest way would be to create an overload of the `Invoke` method that takes an `Action` delegate rather than a `Func`:

```
public static void Invoke(Action action, int tryCount, TimeSpan tryInterval)
{
    if (tryCount < 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("tryCount");
    }

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (--tryCount > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(tryInterval);
                continue;
            }
            LogError(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Oh ok. Can you please show me an example of how to do that?

Comment: @methuselah just copy that code to a new method. Make the return type void and remove the generics from it, and change `Func<T>` for  `Action`, and `return func();` for `func(); return;`

Comment: Fantastic - you've helped me so much!

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicate code (which I'd recommend) and don't care for a bit of extra overhead, you could do: `public static void Invoke(Action action, int tryCount, TimeSpan tryInterval) { Invoke(() => { action(); return 0; } , tryCount, tryInterval); } `. This has some slight overhead but avoids duplicate code (so if you ever change the `Invoke<T>` method you won't need to redo it on the other overload)